# Not able to connect to a container(Created via Rest API) in Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I am creating a docker container ( using docker run) in a kubernetes Environment by invoking a rest API.
I have mounted the docker.sock of the host machine and i am building an image and running that image from RESTAPI..
Now i need to connect to this container from some other container which is actually started by Kubectl from deployment.yml file.
But when used kubeclt describe pod (Pod name), my container created using Rest API is not there..  **So where is this container running and how can i connect to it from some other container** ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you running the container in the same namespace as namespace with deployment.yml? One of the option to check that would be to run -

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
```

If you are not able to find the docker container there than I would suggest performing below steps -

1. docker ps -a {verify running docker status}
2. Ensuring that while mounting docker.sock there are no permission errors
3. If there are permission errors, escalate privileges to the appropriate level

To answer the second question, connection between two containers should be possible by referencing cluster DNS in below format -

```
"<servicename>.<namespacename>.svc.cluster.local"
```

I would also request you to detail steps, codes and errors(if there are any) for me to better answer the question.

Comment: I think the namespace is default.I am able to see that my Container is running when i used `docker ps` inside the `kubectl exec pods -c container /bin/sh`.So i am exposing 8080 so that I can connect to this port from some other container.I am able to connect to this container by `http://ip-of-container:8080` from some other container running in a pod but what i need is I am exposing this 8080 port using -p 8081:8080..What should be the IP where should i connect to port 8081 ?

Comment: Did you try creating a Kubernetes service for exposed port 8081? If not, can you try doing that and confirm if that lets you connect to it?

Comment: I need to connect to the port 8081 from inside the cluster itself.(i.e from a container that is running inside the cluster).So Why do I need to create a  Kubernetes service for that ?Containers inside a pod/Cluster can communicate with each other without a Kubernetes Service i guess ..

Answer (score 1):

You probably shouldn't be directly accessing the Docker API from anywhere in Kubernetes.  Kubernetes will be totally unaware of anything you manually `docker run` (or equivalent) and as you note normal administrative calls like `kubectl get pods` won't see it; the CPU and memory used by the pod won't be known about by the node interface and this could cause a node to become over utilized.  The Kubernetes network environment is also pretty complicated, and unless you know the details of your specific CNI provider it'll be hard to make your container accessible at all, much less from a pod running on a different node.

A process running in a pod can [access the Kubernetes API directly](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/access-cluster-api/), though.  That page notes that all of the official client libraries are aware of the conventions this uses.  This means that you should be able to directly create a Job that launches your target pod, and a Service that connects to it, and get the normal Kubernetes features around this.  (For example, `servicename.namespacename.svc.cluster.local` is a valid DNS name that reaches any Pod connected to the Service.)

You should also consider whether you actually need this sort of interface.  For many applications, it will work just as well to deploy some sort of message-queue system (*e.g.*, RabbitMQ) and then launch a pool of workers that connects to it.  You can control the size of the worker queue using a Deployment.  This is easier to develop since it avoids a hard dependency on Kubernetes, and easier to manage since it prevents a flood of dynamic jobs from overwhelming your cluster.

Comment: Yeah i totally understand that this is not the best Practice to start a container which is not controlled by kubernetes.   
But I have a use-case that require me to start up a new container every time  a new user logs in.So even though when I try to get inside my container and try to do `docker ps` i am able to see my container that I started from RestAPI.My trouble here is I am exposing a port(8080) inside this container which i need to connect with from some other container.How can i know on which IP my port(8080) is getting exposed ?

Comment: This gets back to my "Kubernetes networking is complicated" comment: it might be the node's IP address, or it might not be reachable at all, and moving it up to the Kubernetes layer would simplify this part of it.